# optimizing date() and strtotime() function calls in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

How can I optimize this:

```
$enddatetime = date("YmdHis", strtotime(date("YmdHis", strtotime($session_date.' '.$session_time)) . " + ".$session_duration." minutes"));
```

eg values:

```
$session_date 2011-01-31
$session_time 19:30:00
$session_duration 100
```

Comment: Thats pretty hard to read, i guess it won't matter much but could you perhaps provide a running script and tell you why you want to optimize that? (Or let me say: In what way. Performance? Readability?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so basically you're taking a cow, turning it into hamburger, sprinkling on a little bit of salt, then gluing the salted hamburger back into a cow yet again.

Why the repeated roundtrips through date->strtotime->date, etc...? That's highly inefficient. PHP's native date/time format is a Unix-style timestamp - seconds since Jan 1/1970.

```
$timeval = strtotime($session_date . ' ' . $session_time);
$adjusted_timeval = $timeval + ($session_duration * 60);
$fancy_datetime = date("YmdHis", $adjusted_timeval);
```

Comment: Hats off for the hamburger cow analogy!!

Answer (score 0):

Best i can think of is:

```
$enddatetime = date("YmdHis", strtotime($session_date.' '.$session_time) + (60*$session_duration));
```